# Primefaces Kiosk

Tags: primefaces, var

I am using Mysql database and there are some inputs fields on my page and depending on users input i need to search my database for the corresponding records.

Records Format:

KioskId Location TransactionId UserName
1       Nashik   1001          Sumit
2       Pune     1002          Ankita

For above record i declared one class

ResultVO.java

```
public class ResultVO{
private Long kioskId;
private Long transactionId;
private String location;
private Long userName;

}
```

My implementation

In managed bean

### AbacusMB.java

```
public class AbacusMB{
private List<ResultVO>recordVOList;
public void searchRecord(){
//Mysql query

Which will give me result set

for(i=0;i<resultset.size;i++){
ResultVO record=new ResultVO();

record.setkioskId(resultSet.getLong(0));
//in this way i will set all the properties of this vo
and add this object to list which is used to display records in dataTable
recordVOList.add(record);

}
}
```

---

search.xhtml

```
<p:dataTable value=#{abacusMB.recordVOList} var=record>
<p:column headerText="Kiosk Location">
<h:outputText value=record.location>
<p:column headerText="Transaction Id">
<h:outputText value=record.transactionId>
</p:dataTable>
```

---

But on screen rows are getting added depending on number of records but valus don't get displayed?????????????????

Comment: What do you mean by `values don't get displayed`? You should do an effort on writing your questions, it's very hard to read your code it's highly bugged as shown here. The `search.xhtml` is 100% garbage!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the EL notation for each record.

```
 <h:outputText value="#{record.location}"/>

<h:outputText value="#{record.transactionId}"/>
```

Also, make sure to close all of your tags.